# What's the difference between Html.Label, Html.LabelFor and Html.LabelForModel

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

What's the difference between `@Html.Label()`, `@Html.LabelFor()` and `@Html.LabelForModel()` methods?

Comment: its all in the name. One is for general labels, one is for specific model property labels, and one for general model labels.

Comment: @FranciscoAfonso That doesn't really explain what they actually do, though.

Answer (score 120, accepted):

`Html.Label` gives you a label for an input whose name matches the specified input text (more specifically, for the model property matching the string expression):

```
// Model
public string Test { get; set; }

// View
@Html.Label("Test")

// Output
<label for="Test">Test</label>
```

`Html.LabelFor` gives you a label for the property represented by the provided expression (typically a model property):

```
// Model
public class MyModel
{
    [DisplayName("A property")]
    public string Test { get; set; }
}

// View
@model MyModel
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Test)

// Output
<label for="Test">A property</label>
```

`Html.LabelForModel` is a bit trickier. It returns a label whose `for` value is that of the parameter represented by the model object. This is useful, in particular, for custom editor templates. For example:

```
// Model
public class MyModel
{
    [DisplayName("A property")]
    public string Test { get; set; }
}

// Main view
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Test)

// Inside editor template
@Html.LabelForModel()

// Output
<label for="Test">A property</label>
```

Comment: is it `@Html.EditorFor(m => Test)` or `@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Test)` ?

Answer (score 13):

`Html.Label` - Just creates a label tag with whatever the string passed into the constructor is

`Html.LabelFor` - Creates a label for that specific property. This is strongly typed. By default, this will just do the name of the property (in the below example, it'll output MyProperty if that Display attribute wasn't there). Another benefit of this is you can set the display property in your model and that's what will be put here:

```
public class MyModel
{
    [Display(Name="My property title")
    public class MyProperty{get;set;}
}
```

In your view:

```
Html.LabelFor(x => x.MyProperty) //Outputs My property title
```

In the above, LabelFor will display `<label for="MyProperty">My property title</label>`. This works nicely so you can define in one place what the label for that property will be and have it show everywhere.

Comment: This isn't really what `LabelForModel` is for - see my answer.

Answer (score 8):

I think that the usage of `@Html.LabelForModel()` should be explained in more detail.

The LabelForModel Method returns an HTML label element and the property name of the property that is represented by the model.

You could refer to the following code:

**Code in model:**

```
using System.ComponentModel;

[DisplayName("MyModel")]
public class MyModel
{
    [DisplayName("A property")]
    public string Test { get; set; }
}
```

**Code in view:**

```
@Html.LabelForModel()
<div class="form-group">

    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Test, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })

    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Test)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Test)
    </div>
</div>
```

**The output screenshot:**

[image]

[Reference to answer on the asp.net forum](https://forums.asp.net/t/2071442.aspx?How+do+we+use+Html+LabelForModel+#5978880)

Answer (score 4):

suppose you need a label with text customername than you can achive it using 2 ways

```
[1]@Html.Label("CustomerName")

[2]@Html.LabelFor(a => a.CustomerName)  //strongly typed
```

2nd method used a property from your model. If your view implements a model then you can use the 2nd method.

More info please visit below link

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/01/10/asp-net-mvc-2-strongly-typed-html-helpers.aspx

Comment: What about Html.LabelForModel ?

Comment: returns a label with a string that represents the model, like they all do what their name says...

Comment: sorry I never seen and used @html.LableForModel :)

Comment: see below link                                     http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/system.web.mvc.html.labelextensions.labelformodel%28v=vs.98%29.aspx