# Using an Editor Template for a List

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have something like this

```
public class ResumeVm
{
    public ResumeVm()
    {
        EducationVms = new List<EducationVm>();
    }

    public Guid UserId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public List<EducationVm> EducationVms { get; set; }
}

 public class WorkExperienceVm
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
    }
```

I now want to make an editor template for each of the EducationVms, I made a Template for 1 Education Vm and tried to use

```
@Html.EditorForModel("WorkExperienceVm")
```

but it does not know how to pass in the EducationVms

If I do

```
@Html.EditorForModel("WorkExperienceVm", @Model.EducationVms )
```

It gets made as it expects only 1 Vm to be sent in.

// View (WorkExperienceVm)

```
@model ViewModels.WorkExperienceVm
@Model.Title
```

Comment: Can you show the code for WorkExperienceVm editor and ViewModels.WorkExperienceVm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `EditorForModel` overload that you're using is incorrect. `EditorForModel` produces an editor template for the *current* model (i.e. the `ResumeVm`) and the string you're passing in is the [additional view data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff406445%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) object, not the name of the view.

I'm assuming that "WorkExperienceVm" is the name of the view. Try using `EditorFor`:

```
@for(int i = 0; i < Model.EducationVms.Count; i++)
{
    Html.EditorFor(m => m.EducationVms[i], "WorkExperienceVm")
}
```

An alternative is to create a template that's actually called `EducationVm.cshtml` and type it to `EducationVm`, then you can just do the following and the framework will figure out that you want the template called for each item in the collection:

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.EducationVms)
```

Unfortunately this approach can't be achieved using `UIHint`s or passing in the view name manually into the helper, though that's fairly unlikely to get in your way if you don't mind adhering to strict naming conventions for your templates.

I wrote [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16346179/whats-the-difference-between-html-label-html-labelfor-and-html-labelformodel/16346831#16346831) a while ago explaining the differences between the different helpers for editor templates. It deals specifically with the "label" helpers but the same principles apply to the "editor" helpers.

Comment: Yes, WorkExperienceVm is the name of the editor template. Then what advantage is your code over just a loop the code in the main View(other than I guess being cleaner). Does it handle the "ids" right and stuff?

Comment: @chobo2 There are one or two bugs in the framework regarding producing `name` strings for collections in certain scenarios, but this one should work if your editor template is typed to a single instance of `EducationVm`.

Comment: The scenario I'm talking about in my previous comment is when the model itself is the collection (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18934391/namefor-generates-incorrect-name-when-iterating-over-collection-in-editor-templa) which isn't the case here, so you should be fine.

Comment: still not clear the advantages of having this in an EditorFor vs just foreach loop in Resume View.

Comment: @chobo2 The advantage is the same as any editor template - you can reuse it anywhere.

Comment: hmm and if your not planning to use it anywhere, it is also not setup to be some generic template that could be used for different scenarios.

Comment: Well, whether or not you actually choose to use an editor template is entirely up to you, but your question was based on the premise of using editor templates, so my answer is too.

Comment: @chobo2 I've added another approach that you might prefer.